# Linux:command to append

Tags: linux, append

I have a file name with mailids.csv the data is in the format of

```
eid | emailid| date
```

under which it has 1000000 fields.

```
1| a1@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
2| a2@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
3| a3@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
4| a4@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
5| a5@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
6| a6@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
7|a7@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
8|a8@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
1000000| a1000000 | 2013-09-20 02:23:18
```

Now i want to append '|file' to 'eid|emailid|date' and for first 500000 'Y' should be appended and for the next 500000 'N' should be appended.

Can you please help me out in appending like mentioned above using linux command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three conditions depending on the number of line. In all of them, you can append some text to `$0`, that is, to the entire line.

```
awk 'NR==1 {$0=$0"|date"} NR>=2 && NR<=50000 {$0=$0"|Y"} NR>50000 {$0=$0"|N"}1' file
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==1`  stands for number of line. So when we do `NR==n {}` it means that the commands inside `{}` will be performed for line number `n`.
- Then `$0=$0"|date"` means that some text will be appended at the end of the line, as `$0` stores the whole line. Same for other cases.

#### Test

Given your input:

```
$ cat a
1| a1@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
2| a2@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
3| a3@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
4| a4@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
5| a5@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
6| a6@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
7|a7@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
8|a8@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18
```

It would output (note I use 5 instead of 50,000):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {$0=$0"|date"} NR>=2 && NR<=5 {$0=$0"|Y"} NR>5 {$0=$0"|N"}1' a
1| a1@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|date
2| a2@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|Y
3| a3@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|Y
4| a4@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|Y
5| a5@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|Y
6| a6@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|N
7|a7@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|N
8|a8@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|N

1| a1@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|date
2| a2@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|Y
3| a3@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|Y
4| a4@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|Y
5| a5@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|Y
6| a6@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|N
7|a7@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|N
8|a8@xyz.com|2013-09-20 02:23:18|N
```

Comment: Hi i got the desired output which i wanted. Can you please explain the command in detailed? what exactly the string 'NR==1 {$0=$0"|date"}' mean?

Comment: `NR==1` {}` means that the command inside `{}` will be executed just for the line number 1. Then `$0=$0"|date"` means that some text will be appended at the end of the line, as `$0` stores the whole line.

Comment: $ awk 'NR==1 {$0=$0"|date"} NR>=2 && NR<=5 {$0=$0"|Y"} NR>5 {$0=$0"|N"}1' a. What does number 1 indicates at closing of the quotes i mean at NR>5 {$0=$0"|N"}1' a

Comment: Sorry, was busy. I updated my answer some minutes ago. `1` is a bit tricky. I think you can get the explanation very well from http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ , which is the source I used the most when I began with `awk`.

Comment: The thing is `1` (or any number bigger than 0) evaluates the sentence as true, so it performs the default behaviour of awk: `print $0`. So 1 alone means `print $0`.

Comment: hi instead of using awk can it be done using sed command and if yes can you please tell how it could be done?

Comment: Hi @user2811333 I guess it can be done, of course. I am more familiar with awk, so I cannot figure it how to do it in a easy way. I recommend you to check some manual of sed and ask a different question if you are not able to get the complete result.

Comment: how can i reorder the input string using sed commad(eg: input string: bill gates. the ouput should be gates bill)? can you please help me out? I tried using the command-echo Lakshman Sarath Mr | sed 's/(w+) (w+) (w+)/3 2 1/' . But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

unsure if I understand the format but here is a simple way:

```
cat 1.txt 
sd
asd
asd
asd
asd
ada
asd


awk '{if (NR > 2) { print $0"|Y"} else { print $0"|N"}}' 1.txt 
sd|N
asd|N
asd|Y
asd|Y
asd|Y
ada|Y
asd|Y
|Y
```

Where NR is the line number and I am adding N at the end of the line you could further split using `awk -F"|"  print $1"|"$2"|N"`

**UPDATE sed method**

As requested and whilst possible using sed, the overall calls required becomes a lot more complicated, awk in itself is a programming language and allows you to really get specific per Next Row (Line number) character pattern and in short you are parsing each line/row at a time whilst sed is really used for more pattern match and replace. None the less it is still possible and here is an example changing some random file the first three lines as yes and the rest of the file as N at the end of the line...

```
cat a1
asdas
asd
asd
as
das
d
aa
sd
sa
dsa
```

Actual file above:

Now sed line executed to make the changes:

```
file=a1; lines=$(wc -l < $file);sed "1,3 s/$/Y/" $file|sed "4,$lines s/$/N/"
```

Produces:

```
asdasY
asdY
asdY
asN
dasN
dN
aaN
sdN
saN
dsaN
```

Comment: hi instead of using awk can it be done using sed command and if yes can you please tell how it could be done?

Comment: Hi user2811333 I have updated my answer to include a sed way but I would say stick with awk since its a lot cleaner

Comment: how can i reorder the input string using sed commad(eg: input string: bill gates. the ouput should be gates bill)? can you please help me out? I tried using the command-echo Lakshman Sarath Mr | sed 's/(w+) (w+) (w+)/3 2 1/' . But its not working.

Comment: Hi user281133, I would suggest raising new sed requests that don't relate to initial question as a new question since that way others can also give their input none the less : here is your answer echo "Lakshman Sarath Mr"|sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]*\) \([a-zA-Z]*\) \([a-zA-Z]*\)/\3 \2 \1/'
Mr Sarath Lakshman
or using awk echo "Lakshman Sarath Mr"|awk -F" " '{print $3" "$2" "$1}'
Mr Sarath Lakshman